# Is it possible to "register" an iPhone App Name?

Tags: iphone, app-store

I was wondering if It is possible to "register" an iPhone App Name before the app goes on the app store?

Example:
A developer comes up with a really clever name for a iphone game.
He wants to register the name before he programs the game so that no one else comes up with the same name.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, you can, but only for a limited amount of time. When I tried it, the time period was 120 days, but this may have been changed to 90 days. **EDIT:** It seems that this is now 180 days, based on the comments below.

A developer can choose enter information about the application before uploading it, but Apple will remove the app and it's meta information if the name is not used within the grace period. You cannot use the name ever again after that.

I have, however, some apps that were rejected on the first review and were never re-submitted. It seems that those names are still available to me. Just don't submit a really lame first submission or Apple will know that you are "parking" the name.

**Here's a [screenshot of my email](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zlgl2.png) from Apple:**

[image: email from apple]

Comment: post your image as a link… the auto shrinking doesnt allow anything to be read at all.

Comment: It is now 180 days, see the [iOS Developer Library](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/8_AddingNewApps/AddingNewApps.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011225-CH13-SW1)

Answer (score 7):

You can squat a name for something like 90 days per recent Apple iTunesConnect changes.  If you do not upload a binary in that time, it will be deleted and you will be unable to use it again.

There exists a loophole I have found though I don't know how long it will stay open. It seems that uploading a binary, any binary, then immediately rejecting it will prevent you from deletion.  I don't condone squatting, but sometimes, apps take longer than 90 days to develop.

Comment: I found out about that loophole by mistake! (I don't squat either, I intended to finish my app in time, I didn't get to though...)

Answer (score 2):

If you have the money, not only submit the name in iTunes Connect, but register a trademark on the name.  If you don't, than someone who does, and gets to market first with any other mobile platform game, might try to take the name from you, or involve you in legal wrangling in an attempt to do so.

You might also want to quietly snap up all the relevant domain names, if you can.

Answer (score 1):

A developer can upload basic information about an app including the name before the binary is ready to be submitted. The developer needs to be set up in iTunes Connect and have an active Developer Agreement.

Comment: Yes, but note that if you don't upload a binary within 90 days, your app name will be rescinded, and you will be unable to ever use it again.