# Someone has used my iPhone app name

Tags: iphone, app-store

12 months ago I developed an iPhone app which was rejected by the app store. I have recently come up with a solution to get round the reason why the app was rejected and was planning on resubmitting. I have just discovered that an app was released less than a month ago with the name I was going to use for my app. Is there any way that I can object to this? Not only did I submit <my iphone app name> but I also own the domains www.<my iphone app name>.com and www.<my iphone app name>.co.uk.

There are a couple of similar questions on here which suggest [trademarking your app name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/634456/how-to-protect-a-name-for-an-iphone-app) to prevent this from happening and also effectively [reserving an app name within the app store](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4368460/is-it-possible-to-register-an-iphone-app-name). I specifically want to know if there is a way of objecting to someone elses name.

EDIT: I am NOT looking for opinions as to whether I will be able to stop the name of my app being used by someone else. I want to know if there is a way of contacting apple about this

Comment: Check to see if you can resubmit the rejected app without changing the name.  It may already be reserved for you.  However if you didn't trademark the name, and somebody else was the first to use it... consulting with an IP attorney in your country may be appropriate.

Comment: "Change your apps name. Not that big of a deal."

Comment: It seems to me that you still have some leverage over the party who took your name.  I wonder if you can some how use your ownership of the domain name to a) get the name back, b) profit on your domain names by selling it to them, or c) compete directly while stealing their customers via your URL.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There doesn't appear to be any way of contacting apple about this.

Answer (score 7):

What branding do you have around your name? Since you haven't released, one could argue that you chose the name after seeing the success of the other application.  If you don't have demonstrable pre-existing art then you don't have much to stand on.

To save time, money and heartache, I would simply change your name.  If you already have a lot invested in the name (marketing, ads, reputation) then the cost of changing your name may outweigh the cost of fighting.

The other argument is it took you 12 months to resubmit.  That will show a lack of interest on your part, and a lack of enthusiasm.  Should apple be required to prevent apps with the same name of a previously reject app from being approved for ever on the off chance they re-submit?

For some insight into Apple's thinking on this:

http://www.wired.com/gadgetlab/2009/11/steve-jobs-to-developer-name-change-not-that-big-of-a-deal/

Short version: choose a different name for your app and move on.

Comment: The only branding I have is the domain names that I own, which I can prove I have owned for over 12 months. I would hope there is still some audit trail of my app being submitted which shows I'm not simply trying to copy the name. As I mentioned, the app that has the same name as mine has only appeared in the app store in the past couple of weeks. If it comes to it I will of course just rename my app, but I was specifically asking if anyone knew of a way to object to another apps name via the developer portal or something (rather than legally) although granted it is probably a long shot.

Answer (score 0):

If they were on the store before you and if you haven't trademarked the name, then it goes to them.  Doesn't matter if you "came up with the name first" or you have the domain names for it, they got to the store first.  Just change the app's name, that's all you can do, unless you own the trademarks (and have owned them before their app came out), then you can go after them.

Comment: I know it's a long shot, but really I got to the app store 12 months ago it just happened to be rejected. I would like to know if there is at least a way to challenge an apps name - via the app store or something, rather than legally. If it's going to cost me more money than registering a new domain name, I'll just rename the app,